# Php UTF 8 issue

Tags: php, html

I am reading a specific field from a database but I am having issues setting the correct charset, I still cant get the accents correctly (à, ã, ê, ...), it shows up as Chinese and question marks characters. is there something wrong in my php code? Thank you .

## PHP

```
<?php
    require 'functions.php';
    require 'config.php';

    $con = connect($config['DB_HOST'], $config['DB_USERNAME'], $config['DB_PASSWORD'],'data_db');
    mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'") OR die(mysql_error());
    $sql_textIntro = "SELECT * FROM INTRO_TEXT";
    $results_textIntro = mysql_query( $sql_textIntro, $con);
?>
```

## HTML

```
<h1>TITLE</h1>
    <?php
        $record = mysql_fetch_array($results_textIntro);
        echo "<p>".$record['TEXT_FIELD'].'</p>';
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: This function is very wrong - `mysql_query`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [mysql_set_charset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php) is the right way to change the charset of the connection (not an SQL query).

You can do it this way:

```
mysql_set_charset('utf8', $link); //Take note that it's utf8 and NOT utf-8 here
```

You should also serve your webpage in UTF-8 and make sure your talble store strings in UTF-8 too.

Take note that functions `mysql_*` were **deprecated** in PHP 5.5.0, and were removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the [MySQLi](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this as the first element inside the `head` tags:
`<meta charset="utf-8">`

[Here](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) is a very good, basic, read on character sets by Joel Spolsky in case you want to understand what is going on :)

(See the section under "There Ain't No Such Thing As Plain Text.")

Answer (score -2):

in my.ini file must 
character-set-server = utf8
if does not helps then see:

have set in html head encoding?

have apache set character set to utf8?